# When my number of goroutine is large, the code will get an error

Tags: go

My code works fine with a small number of goroutine, but a large number of errors can occur with memory and pointers.I guess it is my lock used improperly.Can you help me see the tools I wrote? I have been debugging for a long time but I have no way to start.

I thought about adding a read lock to the clock function.But still will report an error.I also tried to use sync.Map. But it did not solve the problem

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "encoding/json"
    "strings"
    "sync"
    "time"
    "strconv"
)

type UrlArray struct {
    Url string `json:"url"`
    Method string `json:"method"`
    Params string `json:"params"`
}
type MsgRequest struct {
    Command string `json:"command"`
    Concurrent int `json:"concurrent"`
    IncrementalRatio float64 `json:"incrementalRatio"`
    InitialRatio float64 `json:"initialRatio"`
    Intervals int `json:"intervals"`
    UrlArray []UrlArray `json:"urls"`
}
type GroupData struct {
    TotalCount int `json:"totalCount"`
    FailCount int `json:"failCount"`
    SuccessRate float64 `json:"successRate"`
    CostTime float64 `json:"costTime"`
    AvergeTime float64 `json:"avergeTime"`
}
type MsgResponse struct {
    TimeObject map[string]GroupData `json:"timeObject"`
    TotalCount int `json:"totalCount"`
    FailCount int `json:"failCount"`
    SuccessRate float64 `json:"successRate"`
    CostTime float64 `json:"costTime"`
    AvergeTime float64 `json:"avergeTime"`
}
type LevelData struct {
    result map[string]GroupData
    sync.RWMutex
}
type ResultStatic struct {
    result map[string]MsgResponse 
}

var p = fmt.Println
var levelOutput LevelData
var output ResultStatic
var closeAllChan chan int
var isHandle = false


//write to map
func (r *LevelData) recordStatic(url string, status bool, useTimeSec float64) {
    r.Lock()
    defer r.Unlock()
    val, ok := r.result[url]
    if ok {
        val.TotalCount += 1
        val.CostTime += useTimeSec
        if status == false {
            val.FailCount += 1
        }
        val.SuccessRate = 1.00 - (float64(val.FailCount) * 1.00) / (float64(val.TotalCount) * 1.00) 
        val.AvergeTime = val.CostTime / float64(val.TotalCount)
        levelOutput.result[url] = val
        } else {
            failcnt := 0
            if status == false {
                failcnt = 1
            }
            successRate := float64(1 - failcnt)
            val := GroupData{TotalCount: 1, FailCount: failcnt, SuccessRate: successRate, CostTime: useTimeSec, AvergeTime: useTimeSec}
            levelOutput.result[url] = val
        }
}

//get request
func get(url string, params string) {
    start := time.Now()
    data := url + "?" + params
    response, err:= http.Get(data)
    end := time.Now()
    costTime := float64((end.Sub(start)).Seconds())

    if err != nil {
        levelOutput.recordStatic(url, false, costTime)
    } else {
        levelOutput.recordStatic(url, true, costTime)
    }

    defer response.Body.Close()
}   

// post request
func post(url string, params string) {
    start := time.Now()
    response, err := http.Post(url, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", strings.NewReader(params))
    end := time.Now()
    costTime := float64((end.Sub(start)).Seconds())

    if err != nil {
        levelOutput.recordStatic(url, false, costTime)
    } else {
        levelOutput.recordStatic(url, true, costTime)
    }

    response.Body.Close()
}

//clock ticker
func (r *LevelData) clock(urlArrays []UrlArray, concurrent int, initialRatio float64, incrementalRatio float64, intervals int) {
    start := int(float64(concurrent) * initialRatio)
    increment := int(float64(concurrent) * incrementalRatio)
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Duration(intervals) * time.Second)
    endtotal := increment + concurrent
    objectKey := 0

    for range ticker.C {
        select {
        case <-closeAllChan:
            p("死循环退出")
            return 
        default:
            if objectKey != 0 {
                for _, v := range(urlArrays) {
                    val1, ok1 := output.result[v.Url]
                    p(val1, ok1)
                    if !ok1 {
                        val1 = MsgResponse{}
                        val1.TimeObject = make(map[string]GroupData)
                    }
                    val1.TimeObject[strconv.Itoa(objectKey)] = levelOutput.result[v.Url]

                    val1.TotalCount += (val1.TimeObject[strconv.Itoa(objectKey)]).TotalCount
                    val1.FailCount += (val1.TimeObject[strconv.Itoa(objectKey)]).FailCount
                    val1.CostTime += (val1.TimeObject[strconv.Itoa(objectKey)]).CostTime
                    val1.SuccessRate = 1.00 - (float64(val1.FailCount) * 1.00) / (float64(val1.TotalCount) * 1.00) 
                    val1.AvergeTime = val1.CostTime / float64(val1.TotalCount)
                    output.result[v.Url] = val1
                }
            } 

            levelOutput = LevelData{result: map[string]GroupData{}}

            if start >= endtotal {
                p("start == concurrent")
                close(closeAllChan)
                time.Sleep(time.Second)
                return
            }

            if objectKey == 0 {
                for i := 0; i < start; i++ {
                    go work(urlArrays)
                }
            } else {
                for i := 0; i < increment; i++ {
                    go work(urlArrays)
                }
            }

            objectKey += 1
            start += increment
        }
    }
}

//work
func work(urlArrays []UrlArray) {
    i := 0
    for {
        select {
        case <-closeAllChan:
            return 
        default:
            index := i % len(urlArrays)
            i++

            url := urlArrays[index].Url
            method := urlArrays[index].Method
            params := urlArrays[index].Params

            if method == "Get" {
                get(url, params)
            } else {
                post(url, params)
            } 
        }
    }
} 

func setupResponse(w *http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    (*w).Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    (*w).Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS")
    (*w).Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization")
}


func myfunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    setupResponse(&w, r)
    if (r).Method == "OPTIONS" {
        return
    }

    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    defer r.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), 501)
        return 
    }
    //json decode
    var msgs MsgRequest
    err = json.Unmarshal(b, &msgs)
    if err != nil {
        p(err.Error())
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), 502)
        return
    }

    var command = msgs.Command

    if command == "stop" {
        p("stop start")
        if isHandle {
            close(closeAllChan)
            isHandle = false 
        } else {
            p("no handle")
            http.Error(w, "未有数据在执行", 504)
            return
        }
    } else if command == "get" {
        p("get start")
        if isHandle {
            p(output.result)
            js, err := json.Marshal(output.result)
            if err != nil {
                http.Error(w, err.Error(), 503)
                return
            }
            w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
            w.Write(js)
        } else {
            p("no handle")
            http.Error(w, "未有数据在执行", 504)
            return
        }
    } else {
        isHandle = true
        closeAllChan = make(chan int)
        output = ResultStatic{result: map[string]MsgResponse{}}
        urlArrays := msgs.UrlArray
        concurrent := msgs.Concurrent
        initialRatio := msgs.InitialRatio
        incrementalRatio := msgs.IncrementalRatio
        intervals := msgs.Intervals
        levelOutput.clock(urlArrays, concurrent, initialRatio, incrementalRatio, intervals)
        isHandle = false
        js, err := json.Marshal(output.result)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), 503)
            return 
        }
        p(output.result)

        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        w.Write(js) 
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/handle", myfunc)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}


// json example
// {
//  "command": "handle/get/stop",
//  "concurrent": 100,
//  "initialRatio": 0.60,
//  "incrementalRatio": 0.20,
//  "intervals": 10,
//  "urls": [
//      {
//          "url": "http://google.com",
//          "method": "GET",
//          "params": ""    
//      }
//  ]
// }
```

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x40 pc=0x6782c4]

goroutine 64655 [running]:
main.post(0xc00001e0c0, 0x3c, 0xc000188510, 0x2f)
    /root/toolv2.go:114 +0x1b4
main.work(0xc000391380, 0x1, 0x4)
    /root/toolv2.go:193 +0xcf
created by main.(*LevelData).clock
    /root/toolv2.go:161 +0x657
exit status 2
```

Comment: Have you tried running it with race detector? `go run -race toolv2.go`? Also try to make your example shorter, aim for a [mcve].

Comment: The code should be the error of the clock function.thank you,i will try it

Comment: so i should delete derfer body.close()?i try it, but there will be lots of errors

Answer (score 4):

"invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference" does not indicate a data race. You are dereferencing a pointer that is nil:

```
func post(url string, params string) {
    start := time.Now()
    response, err := http.Post(url, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", strings.NewReader(params))
    end := time.Now()
    costTime := float64((end.Sub(start)).Seconds())

    if err != nil {
        levelOutput.recordStatic(url, false, costTime)
    } else {
        levelOutput.recordStatic(url, true, costTime)
    }

    response.Body.Close()
}
```

You must not dereference response after an error occurs, because then response is nil.

Comment: i try your code, but there will be error panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x40 pc=0x6782b4]

Comment: That's *your* code, not mine. I just added it to point out one of the problematic functions.

Comment: I posted all the code because I feel that I should have more than one error.thank you very much for your help

Comment: @kscoHZNU_ you're calling `response.Body.Close()` regardless of whether `http.Post` returned an error or not, if `err` is not `nil` then `response` will be `nil`, and when you select a field of a `nil` struct you get the "invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference" error. Simply fix this by *NOT* calling `response.Body.Close()` when `err != nil`.

Comment: you mean ```if err != nil {
  levelOutput.recordStatic(url, false, costTime)
  response.Body.Close()
 }  ```?

Comment: @kscoHZNU_ No, the opposite `... } else { levelOutput.recordStatic(url, true, costTime); response.Body.Close() }`. Or `if err != nil { levelOutput.recordStatic(url, false, costTime); return }`

Comment: I tried your second method and it worked fine. But new questions have emerged. Why the increase in my concurrent volume did not increase the total number of visits. Thank you very much for your solution.